# A man eats a ghost

Tags: story-identification, tv

I saw this on UK TV sometime (I think) in the late 1980s, it was like an outer limits type show ... But not actually Outer Limits.

There was a chubby man who got another to help him in an old house - he was a gourmet who'd eaten most things, I think he'd even tried cannibalism.

One thing he really wanted to try was eating a ghost so they set up some kind of electronic trap and caught one (a Victorian man IIRC) and then he produced a little burner set and frying pan and cooked up the ectoplasm.

He sat and guzzled it while the other watched and looked nauseated - it finished with him frowning because now there was nothing new left to try

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the 1984 made-for-TV movie *[The Gourmet](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0242490/?ref_=tt_urv)*.

> A rich old gourmet that has decided to taste all there is of exotic
> meals has already tried the most, even human flesh, when he gets a tip
> from a rich midget. The midget had tasted everything out of this
> world, and even something not of this world. In other words, a ghost.
> The gourmet gets very interested and the midget gives him the info
> that is needed. And once he has found a haunted place, all he has to
> do is wait for the ghost to turn up so he can have the most exotic
> meal in his career as a [feinschmecker](https://m.interglot.com/de/en/Feinschmecker).

It might interest you to learn that that screenplay was written for Channel 4 by a younger [Kazuo Ishiguro](https://www.npr.org/sections/thesalt/2017/10/15/557217635/nobel-laureate-kazuo-ishiguro-once-wrote-a-screenplay-about-eating-a-ghost?t=1656228208426), who went on to write *The Remains of the Day* and *Never Let Me Go*.

Comment: That's one of the best things about this website -- being introduced to SF movies whose YouTube videos have had only 7058 views. Now 7059.

Comment: what a weird movie. but interesting :)